# How to print a text file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding and am having some issues printing a text file.
Here's my file:

```
Player1: 1  
Player2: 3
```

Here's my code:

```
try:
    scoreTable = open("scoreTable.txt", "r")
    line = scoreTable.readlines()
    for i in range(0, (len(line))):
        print(scoreTable.read(len(line[i].strip("\n"))))
    scoreTable.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

At the moment its just printing whitespace.
I'm probably missing something obvious or have gone down the wrong road altogether, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below code sample to print the whole file.

```
try:
    with open("scoreTable.txt", "r" ) as scoreTable:
        file_content = scoreTable.read()
        print str(file_content)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print e.message
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing `read` operation on `scoreTable.txt` twice, which is not required.

```
try:
    scoreTable = open("scoreTable.txt", "r")
    lines = scoreTable.readlines()
    #here in lines you have whole file stored so no need to try to read from files variable again
    for line in lines:
        print line
    scoreTable.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

While we are on this subject use `with` statement to read files(so you wont have to keep track to close the file)

```
with open("scoreTable.txt", "r" ) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line
```

Comment: You can do `for line in f: print line.strip()` as well. No need to store `lines`.